# How to send automatically the same email to several users from code in Odoo8?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I am sending an email in Odoo 8 from Python code to several users.

To do that I am using `send_mail` method from `email.template` model, but, as I have to pass only one user ID to this method, I have to do a loop to send the mail to all users:

```
for user in users:
    if user.partner_id and user.partner_id.email:
        mails_sent &= self.pool.get('email.template').send_mail(
            self.env.cr, 1, template.id,
            user.id, force_send=True, context=context)
```

My question is:

How can I send one email to all users instead of one email to each user?

Comment: I'm not sure... But maybe this will be helpful. In the system exists object `mail.mail`. This object have field: *recipient_ids*. It seems as we can use this field to send automatically the same email to several users. You can find form for `mail.mail` here: **Settings(top menu)->Technical(section in left menu)->Emails**.

Answer (score 0):

you need see hr odoo 8

inherit your class with mail.thread

```
_inherit = ['mail.thread']
#.....
#after that you can call

id_msg = self.message_post(
              cr, uid, False,
              body=message,
              partner_ids=[id1,id2,id3],
              subtype='mail.mt_comment', context=context
          )
```

i hope this help you :)